# Java - URL Connection in Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, url, connection

I currently have a project where different parameters are requested from an online CGI file, and each request is supposed to be processed in different threads. When I run my code by itself it works great, however it doesn't seem to connect when I put it in a thread. 
My code is below:

```
public void run() {
    connect();
}


public synchronized void connect(){
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer("");
    try {

        String data = "year=" + year + "&top=" + numNames + "number=";
        // Send data
        URL url = new URL("http://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();
        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
System.out.println(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the `connect` method belongs to an object instance that is used by more than one thread, only one will run at a time, but I suspect that's not what you intended to ask. OTOH, if `connect` doesn't alter anything outside itself, there may be no reason for it to be `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the synchronized call on connect.  That should solve your problem

public <strike>synchronized</strike> void connect(){